# Print utf-8 in C on Windows

Tags: c, windows, utf-8

I am looking for a way of printing characters which are represented in UTF-8 as an array of bytes. I've found this approach (below), but I didn't get the expected result あ. Instead of it, I got Russian letters уБВ.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    char s[]={0xe3,0x81,0x82, 0x00};
    printf("%s",s);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Could you kindly advise me the best way of printing utf-8 strings in console? (It is necessary for parsing asn.1 utf-8 strings.)

Comment: although the dupe I linked is for C++, the answer is *exactly* the same. Firstly, you'd have to define what you mean by "console" - different TTYs will act differently vs character encodings.

Comment: Your code is printing UTF-8.  Your *terminal* is not interpreting it as UTF-8, however.

Comment: @TavianBarnes is correct.  I compiled your code and I get あ while on ubuntu terminal ... Please run this in your console    echo -e '\xe2\x82\xac'   ...  you will see €   if your console is UNF-8

Comment: Mac OS X 10.11.6 is also OK with displaying the hiragana.